# How to obtain the size of the message in the vehicular simulator VEINS?

Tags: size, omnet++, veins

I am conducting experiments for vehicular networks using VEINS. One of my objectives is to obtain the size of the message generated by the protocol. After checking the message, I noticed that the size was fixed at 42 Bytes.

how can I obtain the size of the message generated by the protocol?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: did you manage to get the size of the WSM message?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your messages extend `omnetpp::cPacket` class. In that case you may use `getByteLength()` [method](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1cPacket.html#ab015cabcbfe4d6666345876929c5cf29). Otherwise you have to implement a field in your message, which holds a payload size and then read it.